# How to correctly configure a report for average session duration Google spreadsheets (using the GA add-on)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, looker-studio

I am using the Google Sheets add-on for analystics to save my data in Universal Analytics before it gets deleted in July 2024.

My current report config looks like this:

[image]

In the result table I have wild values for the avg. session duration, e.g. 1.810.408.163.265.300 or 158.04.

[image]

I understand that the unit here is seconds, but these numbers still look wild.

As I am planning to use this table as a data source in Looker Studio, I decided not to do any manipulations there.

In Looker Studio, the duration is displayed in the proper format hh:mm:ss. However, if I compare these values to the original data in the UA dashboard. They do not match.

In Google Sheets, I tried formatting the column or deviding by 86400 or the total number os sessions as suggested in a different post. However none of that helped.
In Looker Studio, other than setting the field type to Numeric > Duration I am at a loss at what to do.
I also checked whether it's a time zone issue, but it's set to the same time zone everywhere.

How can I make sure that my numbers match? The session values are the same as in UA which makes it even more inexplicable to me that the duration values don't match.
Any help would be much appreciated!